# Windows Phone Silverlight 8.0 - Specify ClientCredentialType to Basic on BasicHttpBinding

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, basichttpbinding

I have a SOAP WebService that has authorizations and requires me to specify the ClientCredentialType to HttpClientCredentialType.Basic.

I normal .NET project I can specify this (either in code or in XML) to connect to my WebService:

```
BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;
mySoapClient = new MySoapClient(binding, address);
```

The problem is that in a Portable Class Library (PCL) or in a Windows Phone 8.0 Silverlight C# project the property Transport does not exist.

Is there a workaround?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find out the answer.
Looks like all request must be performed within a OperationContextScope.

```
        private void InvokeWebMethod(Action webMethod, string username = null, string password = null)
        {
           using (OperationContextScope contextScope = new OperationContextScope(presenceServer.InnerChannel))
            {
                var bc = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(string.Format(@"{0}:{1}", username ?? this.Username, password ?? this.Password));
                HttpRequestMessageProperty httpProps = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
                httpProps.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(bc);

                OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name] = httpProps;
                webMethod();
            }
        }
```

THanks.